# how to sum values from checklistbox?

Tags: c++, c++builder

I need sum the values from checklistbox. My code is:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::CorrigirClick(TObject *Sender)
{

  int x;
  float soma=0;

  for(x=0; cblOp->Items->Count-1; x++) {
     soma = soma + StrToFloat(cblOp->Items[x]);
  }
   Edit1->Text = FloatToStr(soma);
}
```

I get the following error: *[BCC32 Error] Unit1.cpp(50): E2285 Could not find a match for 'StrToFloat(TStrings)'*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is written as though it can access Delphi default properties, but you need to use somewhat more convoluted code to access them on C++ Builder. Like this:

```
StrToFloat((*(cblOp->Items))[x])
```

However, it is probably clearer and simpler to be explicit about the default property and write this as:

```
StrToFloat(cblOp->Items->Strings[x])
```

Note also that your loop test was incorrect. Your code should be:

```
for(x=0; x < cblOp->Items->Count; x++) 
    soma = soma + StrToFloat(cblOp->Items->Strings[x]);
```

Comment: Actually, Delphi-style "default" properties are accessible in C++, via `operator[]` implementations on the class types. You just need an extra pointer dereference to reach them. In this case, dereference the `Items` object pointer, eg: `StrToFloat((*(cblOp->Items))[x]);` Using `Items->Strings[]` instead is cleaner and more explicit, but the other way works, too.